# Junção de duas tabelas consulta php+mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho duas tabelas: contas a pagar e contas a receber. As duas tabelas tem: código, descricao, datavencimento, datapagamento, datarecebimento e valor.

Como que eu faço uma *query* para pegar os dados das duas tabelas ordenando pela dataVencimento?

Estava usando o *union*:

```
SELECT 
    codigo,
    descricao,
    dataVencimento,
    dataEntrada,
    valor
FROM
    contasReceber
WHERE
    status= "pago" 

    UNION ALL

SELECT 
    codigo,
    descricao,
    dataVencimento,
    dataSaida,
    valor
FROM
    pagamento
order by dataVencimento
```

Mas não consegui pensar numa forma de poder diferenciar as entradas das saidas. Porque eu preciso exibir esses dados, por exemplo:

```
Codigo   Descrição   Pago    Recebido
1        farmacia    20,00   -
2        aluguel     -       30,00
```

Como que eu posso fazer isso usando *javascript+php+mysql*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

continue utilizando o union, porém você deve criar colunas adicionais:

```
SELECT 
r.codigo,
r.descricao,
r.dataVencimento,
r.dataEntrada,
0 as pago,
r.valor as recebido,
'CR' as tipo
FROM
contasReceber r
WHERE
r.status= "pago" 
and r.dataVencimento between '01/08/2017' and '30/08/2017'

UNION

SELECT 
p.codigo,
p.descricao,
p.dataVencimento,
p.dataSaida,
p.valor,
0,
'PG' as tipo
FROM
pagamento p
where p.dataVencimento between '01/08/2017' and '30/08/2017'

order by dataVencimento
```

lembrando que o nome das colunas, seguira o nome da primeira query.

Comment: Não entendi como que essa query irá funcionar. Pode explicar por favor?
Pra que serve esse 0 as recebido e esse 0 as pago? 
E essa coluna tipo?

Comment: @L.J Desculpe a demora, estava viajando, esse 0 as recebido, irá gerar uma coluna com valor 0 quando a linha vier da tabela contas a receber, e igualmente para a outra tabela. O tipo, apenas pra diferenciar as linhas, e te mostrar que você pode gerar outras colunas no select. Quando visualizar o resultado da query, você consegue saber qual linha veio de qual tabela.

Comment: Então não deveria ser na primeira query 0 as pago pq ele vai ta selecionando as contas que ele irá receber. E na de baixo que ele ta selecionando os pagamentos não deveria ser 0 as recebido, já que ele está selecionando pagamentos então a coluna recebido tem que 0?

Comment: Entendi agora. E se eu quiser filtrar a data de vencimento ou a data de pegamento entre duas datas. Como eu usaria o BETWEEN nessa query?
Fis isso: dataVencimento between '01/08/2017' AND '30/08/2017' mas não está dando certo.
Ele ta dando o erro: Unknown column 'dataPagamento' in 'where clause'

Comment: Isso era pra funcionar mas não está funcionando. 
Unknown column 'dataVencimento ' in 'where clause'

Comment: @L.J testa agora.

Comment: Deu esse erro: Unknown column 'r.dataVencimento' in 'where clause'

Comment: tem certeza que essa coluna existe na sua tabela ? coloca a estrutura delas aí por favor

Comment: Funcionou...era porque eu estava usando date format e tava usando
DATE_FORMAT(r.data_vencimento,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dataVencimento.
Ai eu tava pegando   dataVencimento.e não r.data_vencimento
Ai tava dando esse pau mas agora funfou.
Vlw cara!!!